# Prevent UILabel text color change from overriding placeholder text color change in swift

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to make global color changes to an iOS app. I'm running into an issue where changes to `UILabel.appearance().textColor` propagate to UITextField placeholder text. The solutions that I've seen for this problem involve setting attributed strings or digging into private members of UITextField. How can I globally change the color of UILabel text color and also the placeholder text on a text field? I've tried the code below, but I end up with all green text.

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.greenColor()

// UITextField placeholder color
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UITextField.self]).textColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```

Comment: so you want to change UILabel text color and UITextField text color only? UITextField text color and all other color should be same?

Comment: @Pyro I want to change the two controls independent of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify placeholder text color using UIAppearance. (Only properties declared with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` are available that way.) Your safest option is to use a UITextField subclass; here's one to make the color manageable in Interface Builder.

```
@IBDesignable class PCTextField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor() {
        didSet {
            if let placeholder = self.placeholder {
                let colorAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor]
                attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: colorAttribute)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're doing your color changes in code, then assigning `placeholderColor` from an NSUserDefaults setting would fit in reasonably smoothly with UIAppearance based management.

Comment: This is a very nice solution to my stated problem. I like the storyboard config options.